# Make image clickable in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uitextview

I am trying to create a notetaking app where you can click on images as well as edit text normally.

Currently, I have placed a  tap gesture recognizer over the UITextView which calls:

```
    @IBAction func onImageTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.state == .ended {
            let textView = sender.view as! UITextView
            let layoutManager = textView.layoutManager

            // location of tap in textView coordinates
            var location = sender.location(in: textView)
            location.x -= textView.textContainerInset.left;
            location.y -= textView.textContainerInset.top;

            // character index at tap location
            let characterIndex = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: location, in: textView.textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

            // if index is valid
            if characterIndex < textView.textStorage.length {

                // check if the tap location has the image attribute
                let attributeValue = textView.attributedText.attribute(NSAttributedString.Key.fileType, at: characterIndex, effectiveRange: nil) as? String
                // if location does have custom attribute, extract the url of the PDF and perform segue to display PDF
                if let value = attributeValue {
                    if value == "PDF" {
                        storedFileName = textView.attributedText.attribute(NSAttributedString.Key.fileName, at: characterIndex, effectiveRange: nil) as? String
                        performSegue(withIdentifier: "displayPDF", sender: textView)
                    }
                } else {
                    textView.isEditable = true
                    textView.becomeFirstResponder()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This makes all of the images clickable. However, then I stop being able to click anywhere else in the UITextView to edit the text.

**What do I do so that the images remain clickable but, if I click anywhere else in the UITextView, I am able to start editing the text?**

Comment: `textView.becomeFirstResponder()` makes it editable but you're calling it only if  `attributeValue` is null. You should consider other condition blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have added the image to the `UITextView` as an `NSAttachment`, as of iOS 9.0 you can check whether or not a given `NSRange` contains an attachment:

#### For instance, if the image was located at the 25th character:

```swift
let characterIndex = 25
let range = NSRange(location: characterIndex, length: 1)

// Using an IBOutlet in the current view controller called 'textView'
if textView.attributedText.containsAttachments(in: range) {
    // Do some activity
}
```